# custom char 2D array sorting function

Tags: c++

The sorting won't take place no matter how i try

I think their is some error in my "if" function, my comparison isn't working thats why the loop won't work

```
void sort_func(char name[5][10]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if(name[i][j] > name[i + 1][j]) {
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    temp[k] = name[i][k];
                    name[i][k] = name[i + 1][k];
                    name[i][k] = temp[k];
                }

            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char names[5][10];

    cout << "Enter five Names" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> names[i];
    }
    sort_func(names);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(name[i][j] > name[i + 1][j])` -- Ask yourself what is `i + 1` when `i` is 4.  Then compare that with the highest index you can have for the number of rows.

Comment: sorry, i don't get it completely can you re-write and, what should i do. I get it what is going wrong, but couldn't get it right

Comment: What they are getting at is that if `i` is `4`, then `i+1 == 5` and then you try to access the sixth element in the array (since indexing starts at zero).

Comment: can anyone tell me how can I make this work..... i am busting my head over this please...!!!, I fixed this out of bound think for "if" loop still i can't make it work

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger yet, add some debug printing so that you can follow what the program does. `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { std::cout << name[i] << "\n"; ...` for example. It will print all the names. Then read what @PaulMcKenzie wrote again. If you print all the names using `name[i]`, what do you expect `name[i+1]` to do? You are accessing memory outside your array and the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why not use `std::sort` with a custom comparitor (function object or lambda)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort doesn't work because it is not a sorting code.

What your code does:

Outermost loop (`for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`) iterate through all the words only once. Second loop ( `for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)`
) iterates through the characters in each word. Basically, you compare your 1st word with 2nd word in first iteration of outermost loop and swap the word if first character is smaller. In second iteration, you compare 2nd word with 3rd word. Likewise for other iterations.

If you are aiming for `selection` sort, you should compare each word with all the other words (or unsorted words). It is not happening in your code. I recommend you to read [sorting strategies](http://www.hellgeeks.com/selection-sort/) and try to implement basic sorting using [bubble](http://www.hellgeeks.com/bubble-sort/) or [selection](http://www.hellgeeks.com/selection-sort/) sort. Also as pointed out in comments, use [debugger](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/index.htm) or `print statements` to understand the control flow and working of your program.

If you change your loop to the following, then the sorting will work (Note: For simplicity, below code will only check the first character of each word and sort accordingly)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < 5; j++) { // iterates through words starting from i+1. Also j < no of words)
            if(name[i][0] > name[j][0]) { // Here first word name[i][0] is compared with all other words name[j][0]
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    temp[k] = name[i][k];
                    name[i][k] = name[j][k];
                    name[j][k] = temp[k];
                if(i==4)
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }
```

Changes done in a nutshell:

Change 1:
`for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)` is chanegd to `for(int j = i+1; j < 5; j++)`.  Instead of iterating through all the characters in the word, this loop is used to iterate through the words like the outermost loop. Outermost loop always pick a word (`name[i]`)and it is compared with the other words(using the innermost loop `name[j]`).

Change 2:
 `if(name[i][j] > name[i + 1][j])`  is changed to `if(name[i][0] > name[j][0])`. `if` checks a word with all the remaining words instead of checking a word with only the next word. In the above code, for simplicity, I am only comparing first character of every words for sorting. Instead of comparing character by character you can also use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) to compare the words.

Also, there are lot of improvements that can be made to your code.

Comment: Thank you, this was for my college project.... I'm still figuring out how can i work with 2D array, as i need to iterate through out each char.....As our teacher strickly told us not to use any sorting function